# Firebase image object does not exist?

Tags: ios, firebase, uiimage, firebase-storage

I am currently learning about how to upload/download images to/from Firebase. However, I am encountering two problems:

1. When I upload the image to my Firebase console it says it's type is "application/octet-stream" which is not exactly what I want (I uploaded a jpeg file)

Here's the code:

```
@IBAction func completeSignUpButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let userProfileImageRef = storage.child("userProfileImage")

    //UPloading the photo into firebase
    let data = Data()
    //uploading user profile picture
    if self.userInitialPhoto.image != nil {
        if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.userInitialPhoto.image!) {
            userProfileImageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    return
                } else {
                    print("Image upload success!")
                    //self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "completeRegistrationSegue", sender: self)
                }
            })

        }

    } else {
        print("You need to pick a picture!")

    }

}
```

So this might be the problem that's causing my second problem:

2. When I try to load the image from Firebase to my UIImage in my app, it says Object Optional(\"userID\")/userProfileImage does not exist."

Here's my code for that:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("user Status").document("Current Status")
    self.userStatusTableView.reloadData()
    let referencePath = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "\(userID)/userProfileImage")
    let userProfileImageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("\(userID)/userProfileImage")
    userProfileImageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("There's an eror downloading the image\(error?.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            self.userProfileImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }
}
```

I am wondering what I should do to fix these issues.

Thanks for your help in advance and happy new year to you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while uploading the image to firebase you passed metadata as nil. you need to pass image metadata there

```
let metaData = FIRStorageMetadata()
metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
```

and in upload complitionBlock, you can get URL for that image using

```
if error == nil , let meta = meta {
     if let url = meta.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {
           //use this url to access your image
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks I've got the upload as an jpeg now however I still cannot download the image. When I tried to print the url out it gave me nil. Would you know how to solve this? The image url does exist in my firebase console though